# freecodecamp Golf Code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve Golf Code challenge in freecodecamp and I can't really figure out what is wrong with my code
here is the direct [link](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/golf-code#?solution=function%20golfScore(par%2C%20strokes)%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20below%20this%20line%0A%20%20if(strokes%20%3D%3D%201)%20return%20%22Hole-in-one!%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3C%3D%20par%20-2)%20return%20%22Eagle%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3D%3D%3D%20par%20-1)%20return%20%22Birdie%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3D%3D%3D%20par)%20return%20%22Par%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3D%3D%3D%20par%20%2B%201)%20return%20%22Bogey%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3D%3D%3D%20par%20%2B%202)%20return%20%22Double%20Bogey%22%3B%0A%20%20else%20if(strokes%20%3E%3D%20par%20%2B%203)%20return%20%22Go%20Home%22%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20return%20%22Change%20Me%22%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20above%20this%20line%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Change%20these%20values%20to%20test%0AgolfScore(5%2C%204)%3B%0A). Link contains the code I am trying to run, just visit the link.

**My JS:**

```
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
    if(strokes == 1) return "Hole-in-one!";
    else if(strokes <= par -2) return "Eagle";
    else if(strokes === par -1) return "Birdie";
    else if(strokes === par) return "Par";
    else if(strokes === par + 1) return "Bogey";
    else if(strokes === par + 2) return "Double Bogey";
    else if(strokes >= par + 3) return "Go Home";

return "Change Me";
}
golfScore(5, 4);
```

**Requirement:**

In the game of golf each hole has a par meaning the average number of strokes a golfer is expected to make in order to sink the ball in a hole to complete the play. Depending on how far above or below par your strokes are, there is a different nickname.

Your function will be passed par and strokes arguments. Return the correct string according to this table which lists the strokes in order of priority; top (highest) to bottom (lowest):

Strokes Return:

```
1                  "Hole-in-one!"
<= par - 2         "Eagle"
par - 1            "Birdie"
par                "Par"
par + 1            "Bogey"
par + 2            "Double Bogey"
>= par + 3         "Go Home!"
```

Thanks for help in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much there. The only reason your solution isn't being accepted is because you are returning `Go Home` instead of `Go Home!` (note the exclamation mark at the end).

Answer (score 1):

I feel the solution is cleaner this way. Uses less mental resources. You're not having to invert the args before writing a call.

```js
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"]
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
    // Only change code below this line
    if (1 == strokes) return names[0];
    else if (par -2 >= strokes) return names[1];
    else if (par -1 === strokes) return names[2];  
    else if (par === strokes) return names[3];
    else if (par + 1 === strokes) return names[4];
    else if (par + 2 === strokes) return names[5];
    else if (par + 3 <= strokes) return names[6];
    // Only change code above this line
}
    
// Change these values to test
golfScore(4, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution of Golf Code FCC:

```
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {

  if (strokes == 1) return names[0];
  else if (strokes <= par - 2) return names[1];
  else if (strokes == par - 1) return names[2];
  else if (strokes == par) return names[3];
  else if (strokes == par + 1) return names[4];
  else if (strokes == par + 2) return names[5];
  else if (strokes >= par + 3) return names[6];

  return "Change Me"; // in case: if non-valid input given
}

console.log(golfScore(5, 4));
```

Comment: Comment should begin with `//`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stuck on this in the future, OP's code is logical, it's only the typo of missing the "!" in "Go Home!".

It's a reminder how detailed these type of things are. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
const names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];

function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  // Only change code below this line
if (strokes == 1 ){
  return names[0]
  }else if (strokes <= par-2){
    return names[1]
  }else if (strokes == par-1){
    return names[2]
  }else if (strokes == par ){
    return names[3]
  }else if (strokes== par +1){
    return names[4]
  }else if (strokes== par +2){
    return names[5]
  }else if (strokes >= par +3)

  return names[6];
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate nested if-else statements... Unless they made it in one shot or they are more than 2 shots over par, adding (strokes - par) to the index of "Par" in such an array will return the applicable score.

ie. Par 4, made in 3. Par = 3 in the array, and 3 - 1 = 2 which is Birdie.

I know this is more complicated than the course asks for, but I really dislike nested if-else...

```
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  var arr = ["Eagle", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey"];

  switch(true) {
    case (strokes == 1): return "Hole-in-one!";
    case (strokes - par > 2): return "Go Home!";
    default: return arr[arr.indexOf("Par") + (strokes - par)];
  }
}

// Change these values to test
golfScore(4, 7);
```

Comment: This seems to only work with a given expected par, but the function needs to work with a par *parameter*.

Comment: Apologies, I should've included the entire function. Updated for clarity. It does in fact work based upon receiving par from a parameter.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Feel free to test it at the link in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Basic JavaScript: Golf Code

```
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if(strokes >= par + 3) {
   return names[6];
  } else if(strokes == par + 2) {
   return names[5];
  } else if(strokes == par + 1) {
   return names[4];
  } else if(strokes == 1) {
   return names[0];
  } else if(strokes == par) {
    return names[3];
  } else if(strokes == par - 1) {
    return names[2];
  } else if(strokes <= par - 2) {
    return names[1];
  }  

  return "Change Me";
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if(strokes === 1){
    return names[0];
  }else if(strokes <= par - 2){
    return names[1];

  }else if(strokes === par - 1){
    return names[2];

  }else if(strokes === par){
    return names[3];

  }else if(strokes === par + 1){
    return names[4];

  }else if(strokes === par + 2){
    return names[5];

  }else if(strokes >= par + 3){
    return names[6];

  }


  // Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test
golfScore(5, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The original answer is good but does not make use of the names array provided. I successfully completed the challenge with the following:

```
  // Only change code below this line

  if(strokes == 1) {
  return names[0];
  }
  if(strokes <= par -2) {
  return names[1];
  }
  if(strokes == par -1) {
  return names[2];
  }
  if(strokes == par) {
  return names[3];
  }
  if(strokes == par +1) {
  return names[4];
  }
  if(strokes == par +2) {
  return names[5];
  }
  if(strokes >= par +3) {
  return names[6];
  }
  return "Change Me";

  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my answer

```
var names = ["Eagle", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
// Only change code below this line
  if(strokes == 1) return names[0];
  else if(strokes <= par - 2) return names[1];
  else if(strokes <= par - 1) return names[2];
  else if(strokes == par) return names[3];
  else if(strokes <= par + 1) return names[4];
  else if(strokes <= par + 2) return names[5];
  else {
  return names[6];
  }

  return "Change Me";
// Only change code above this line
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.